# How to set mobile number validation on my jsp page?

Tags: javascript, jsp

i am using this script for validation can  anybody help me  where i am wrong. i am using this foe mobile number validation.when i run this code with jquery  it is not working.

```
    function mobilenumber() {
          if(document.getElementById('mobnum').value != ""){

       var y = document.getElementById('mobnum').value;
       if(isNaN(y)||y.indexOf(" ")!=-1)
       {
          alert("Invalid Mobile No.");
          document.getElementById('mobnum').focus();
          return false;
       }

       if (y.length>10 || y.length<10)
       {
            alert("Mobile No. should be 10 digit");
            document.getElementById('mobnum').focus();
            return false;
       }
       if (!(y.charAt(0)=="9" || y.charAt(0)=="8" || y.charAt(0)=="7"))
       {
            alert("Mobile No. should start with 9 ,8 or 7 ");
            document.getElementById('mobnum').focus();
            return false
       }

    }
    }

 <input type="submit" value="INSERT"class="btn"onclick="submitForm();">
```

jquery  is

```
$(document).ready(function(){
function submitForm(){
    if(mobilenumber()){
        $('#form1').submit(function(){

        });

        }
        else{
            alert("Please Input Correct Mobile Numbers");
        }

}
});
```

Comment: where are you from i mean for which country mobile number you want validation???

Comment: indaia is a country where i am using validation

Answer (score 1):

Use HTML5 Pattern

```
<input type="number" pattern=".{10}" title="Enter Valid Mob No" required>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 var mobile = document.getElementById("mobnum").value;
 var numericmob = isNumber(mobile );
      if(!numericmob)
      {
          alert("Enter only positive numbers into the Contact Number field.");      
          return false;
      }
      if(mobile.length!=10)
      {
          alert("Enter 10 digits Contact Number.");
          return false;
      }
```

// write function that checks element is number or not

```
function isNumber(elem)
{    
    var re = /^[0-9]+$/; 
    str = elem.toString();
    if (!str.match(re)) 
    {               
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Advantage of this function is you can use it for checking *any numeric* field on your form, such as id, amount etc.

Answer (score 0):

Use jQUery .submit() function to submit the form after validation is true

```
<form id="myForm" action="abc.php" method="post">

<!-- Your Form -->

<button onclick="submitForm();">Submit</button>
</form>
```

now to check if form data is valid here

```
function submitForm(){
    if(mobilenumber()){
        $('#myForm').submit();
        }
        else{
            alert("Please Input Correct Mobile Numbers");
        }
}
```

EDIT:
Use the @Aniket's isNumber function to check length and digit in mobile number field. Which is more generic.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(document.getElementById('mobile_number').value != ""){

   var y = document.getElementById('mobile_number').value;
   if(isNaN(y)||y.indexOf(" ")!=-1)
   {
      alert("Invalid Mobile No.");
      document.getElementById('mobile_number').focus();
      return false;
   }

   if (y.length>10 || y.length<10)
   {
        alert("Mobile No. should be 10 digit");
        document.getElementById('mobile_number').focus();
        return false;
   }
   if (!(y.charAt(0)=="9" || y.charAt(0)=="8" || y.charAt(0)=="7"))
   {
        alert("Mobile No. should start with 9 ,8 or 7 ");
        document.getElementById('mobile_number').focus();
        return false
   }
```

}

try this... this will be needful for you... and if you are looking for ragex pattern then use this....

```
^([0|\+[0-9]{1,5})?([7-9][0-9]{9})$
```